# C# store app update stackpanel.width in code

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

How can I update the width of a stackpanel/border in code?

when i try to get values like

```
var width = stackpanel.width;
```

or

```
var width = Convert.ToDouble(stackpanel.width);
```

I get NaN, which i find very strange.

What i want to do is: set the width of a stackpanel with the width of 2 other stackpanels.
like this:

```
Stackpanel1.width = StackpanelA.width + StackpanelB.width;
```

This does not seem to work. Anyone has a simple solution?

Comment: You may be trying to do it before they are drawn. Try and add the code into the StackPanel's Loaded event and see if you get a value. Or, find another way make it work (such as putting them all in a Grid).

Comment: put this code in Windows_SizeChanged event and see if you are getting the required values

Answer (score 0):

If Width is not explicitly coded the StackPanel will always have NaN width. The property you want is "ActualWidth". So the code would be:

```
Stackpanel1.width = StackpanelA.ActualWidth + StackpanelB.ActualWidth;
```